# EntityFramework6.Npgsql - How to read a column with type "time without time zone"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I have a postgresql database to which I'm connecting using Entity Framework 6 and Npgsql. My table has a column with definition

```
time_column time without time zone
```

I'm trying to read it to a property using entity framework

```
[Column("time_column")]
public TimeSpan Time{ get; set; }
```

However, I when trying to read that table, I rceive an error

```
UNION types interval and time without time zone cannot be matched
```

How should I configure the property for that column in EF class?

Comment: It's highly recommended to upgrade to Entity Framework Core. The old EF6 itself is no longer actively maintained, and the PG provider specifically even less so.

Comment: It's an old project which targets .NET framework 4.8. Therefore I cannot use EF core.

Comment: OK. At the very least post the LINQ query or code reading the table, preferably posting a minimal repro.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TimeOnly** type in your property:

```
public TimeOnly TimeProp { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's very unlikely to be supported by EF6 and/or the Npgsql EF6 provider (always good to verify answers work before posting them).

Comment: Ahahahah... I'm sorry. @Shay, you have reason, and you know well the problem because you is one of the developers of NpgSql project. I didn't have PostgreSql installed and I couldn't try it. Now that I have installed it, I'll think about it a bit and I'll propose a possible solution to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, EF6 doesn't have a Time property, and TimeSpan does not work (after all, its internal structure is different). One solution could be to mark your Time property like **not mapped**, so with EF6 you can still use your classes to manage your PostgreSql database, but obviously the Time field will not be updated automatically. Then you can write the 'get' and the 'set' method of that property to read and write 'Time', issuing some SQL commands, and you should override db.SaveChanges() also.

This code works:

```
using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
{    
    Plan myPlan = new Plan()
    {
        Title = "Good morning",
        Time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 40)
    };    
    db.Plans.Add(myPlan);
    db.SaveChanges();      

    Plan pl = db.Plans.Find(1);          
}

public class Plan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TimeSpan Time
    {                
        get
        {      
            if (Id > 0 && time == new TimeSpan(0,0,0))
            {  
                try
                {                                      
                    string queryString = "SELECT \"Time\" FROM \"dbo\".\"Plans\" WHERE \"Id\"=" + Id + ";";                                        
                    var myTimeSpan = db.Database.SqlQuery<TimeSpan>(queryString).ToList();
                    time = TimeSpan.Parse(myTimeSpan[0].ToString());                        
                }
                catch
                {
                    time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
                }
            };
            return time;
        }    

        set { time = value; }
    }
    private TimeSpan time;
}
```

and into your DbContext class, You can add some code like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var addmod = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(t => t.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Plan) && (t.State == EntityState.Added || t.State == EntityState.Modified))
        .Select(t => t.Entity)
        .ToArray();

    if (addmod.Length > 0)
    {
        int i = base.SaveChanges();

        if (i > 0)
        {
            foreach (var t in addmod)
            {
                Plan myEntity = t as Plan;                            
                string queryString = "UPDATE \"dbo\".\"Plans\" SET " + "\"Time\"=" + "'2023-10-12 "+ myEntity.Time.ToString()+ "' WHERE \"Id\"=" + myEntity.Id.ToString()+";";
                Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(queryString);                            
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
                            
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```